# Is there a way to detect that a USB Ethernet Adapter is connected to an iPhone/iPad programatically?

Tags: ios, xcode, networking, adapter, ethernet

I want to detect if the adapter is connected to the iPhone even if no IP has been given to the iPhone. I can detect that the interface is connected when the iPhone has been given an IP address, but how can I detect the adapter when not?

I can see the Ethernet settings in the iPhone even without IP address.

My configuration is:

Ethernet -> USB-Ethernet adapter -> Lightning to USB adapter -> iPhone.

https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MC704LL/A/apple-usb-ethernet-adapter

https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MK0W2AM/A/lightning-to-usb-3-camera-adapter

Answer (score 0):

After more testing I found out that the iPhone indeed creates a new network interface with a self-assigned IP but it took some time to appear. So for now I can detect that a new interface was detected and that's good enough.